# Regular expression to escape line breaks in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I have a string in PHP that contains Python code, like below:

```
$source_code = "\nprint('Hello\nWorld')\n";
```

I need to escape line breaks between single or double quotes. I want to get something like the following:

```
$source_code = "\nprint('Hola\\nWorld')\n";
```

In other words, simply precede with an `\` any occurrence of `\n` that is contained within single or double quotes. I have this in PHP for now in case single quotes are found:

```
<?php
    $source_code = "\nprint('Hello\nWorld')\n";
    $source_code = preg_replace("/'(.*)(\\n)(.*)'/", "\\n", $source_code);
    echo $source_code;
?>
```

But I am getting: `\nprint(\n)\n`. However, the expected string should be: `\nprint('Hello\\nWorld')\n`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is PHP code and even though the text happens to be python, its not a python related problem. Any text with newlines would do. I think the python tag should be removed.

Comment: Ok ready, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: It would normally take a callback to do this, but it could be done using the `\G` anchor. Unfortunately, you'd have to take into account _Comments_ where quotes are or could be hidden. It's a big job then. It's doable, done it, but is it worth it is the question ...

Comment: The regex for comments is big. But, you'd have a series of alternations, Skip/Fail the comments first, then do the quote checks, one for single, one for double. Get their contents then in replace callback, substitute LF for literal `\n` , etc...

Comment: Anyway this is the regex, capture group 1 is processed in the callback `'~(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\\]|\\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n|$))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|("(?:\\\[\S\s]|[^"\\\])*"|\'(?:\\\[\S\s]|[^\'\\\])*\')|(?:[\S\s][^/"\'\\\]*)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)~'`

Comment: See example here https://regex101.com/r/Q4vxv5/1

Answer (score 0):

you can  use twice replacement, the first is remove the both ends "\n", and then replace the center \n

Comment: The problem is not so simple, consider that I could have the following code `"x=input()\nprint('Hello\nWorld')\n"` and the expected string would be `"x=input()\nprint('Hello\\nWorld')\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Works for single strings only. Feel free to extend if neccessary.

```
$source_code = "x=input()\nprint('Hello\nWorld')\n"; // thx for the test @Hugo :)

$match = preg_match('/(["\'])(.*)\1/s', $source_code, $matches);

if ($match) {
    $text = $matches[2];
    $text = str_replace("\n", '\\\\n', $text);
    $source_code = preg_replace('/(.*)((["\']).*\3)(.*)/s', '$1$3' . addslashes($text) . '$3$4', $source_code);
}

var_dump($source_code);
```

Wokring [example](https://3v4l.org/GaLgD).

Comment: Hi @Pilan your code looks good, you gave me new ideas. Thank you! However, I think it works partially, for example if we have `"foo = ['1', '2', 3]\nprint('HelloWorld\n')"` with your code the output will be `"foo = ['1', '2', 3]\nprint(\', \'2\', 3]\\nprint(\'HelloWorld\\n')"` but correct output is `"foo = ['1', '2', 3]\nprint('HelloWorld\\n')"`.

Comment: As I said, single strings :)